# In-game score counter that depends on time C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a very simple game, I wanted to add a score to it, after that it started to lag a lot, here is my score counter code, I think the problem is in it

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public int scr = 0;
    
    void Update(){
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       scr = scr + 1;
       scoreText.text = scr.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute Update() method each 1000ms, maybe better aproach is to create coroutine executing each 1000ms.

```
void Start(){
       StartCoroutine(SampleCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator SampleCoroutine()
{
       while(true){
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            scr = scr + 1;
            scoreText.text = scr.ToString();
       }
}
```

Comment: `Start` itself can already be the routine ;) just use `IEnuemrator Start`

Answer (score 1):

`Update` is called every frame if i remember correctly.
So what you are doing is every frame pausing the game for a second

try this no way the best solution but it may be a start

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public DateTime starttime

    void Start()
    {
       starttime = DateTime.Now;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = ((int)(DateTime.Now - starttime).TotalSeconds).ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `DateTime.Now` or in general the `DateTime` is pretty expensive!